# Fixed header with mysterious margin in Safari

Tags: css, css-position, margin

In a site I am developing, I want a fixed menu on top that grows when I scroll. It works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but when I try on safari, it adds a margin on top.

The header HTML:

```
<div id="top-background">
    <div id="top-menu">
        <header class="large">
            <nav><img class="logo" src="img/logo-color-solo.png"/>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li><span><a data-scroll href="#de-que-se-trata">¿De qué<br/>se trata?</a></span></li>
              <li><span><a data-scroll href="#beneficios">¿Cuáles son<br/>los beneficios?</a></span></li>
              <li><a data-scroll href="#como-se-usa"><span>¿Cómo se usa?</a></span></li>
              <!--<li><a href="#"><span>¿Cuáles son las<br/>membresías?</a></span></li>-->
              <li><a data-scroll href="#unete"><span>Únete</a></span></li>
            </ul> 
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
...
```

The header CSS:

```
header{ 
   background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95); 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #aaaaaa; 
   float: left; 
   width: 100%; 
   position: fixed; 
   z-index: 10;
}
```

this is how it looks on Chrome/Firefox (the right way)
[image: Chrome/Firefox render]

And this is how it looks on Safari (wrong):
[image]

...as you can see, there is a huge white margin on top. No idea what it is. If I remove the whole CSS code of the header element, the margin disappears. I tried deleting each property individually as well, but I keep seeing the same margin.

Thanx for any help

Comment: why the `float: left`? Also try adding `top: 0` and see what happens

Comment: it seems to be the awto margin-top from the inner image text.

Comment: just add coordonate top:0; ... and eventually left:0; to avoid other unexpected behavior

Comment: i think we need more css to help you. not just the header css. maybe the url if it is already online.

Comment: have you tried **top: 0;** in **header{ }** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `top: 0;` to the navbar, so that the navbar always knows where to stay. Hope this helps :)